# GNU Grub Boot Screen

Tags: boot, gnu

My Asus laptop was working fine and one day, I got an error screen when I started it and the top says "GNU GRUB version 1.99-21ubuntu3.4annan1". The choices after that are:

```
Ubuntu, with Linux 3.2.0-97-generic
Ubuntu, with Linux 3.2.0-97-generic (recovery mode)
Previous Linux versions
Memory Test (memtest86+)
Memory Test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)
Restore Ubuntu to factory state
```

I'm trying to boot it to at least get my documents off before I attempt factory state. Any advice how to boot it because every time I try the first two I can't get past choosing them and then I get a blank screen or just a lot of code and nothing else. I don't have a CD port in my laptop so I can't reboot with physical copy of Ubuntu either.

Thank you in advance,

Rin

Comment: It's not an error. Just the GRUB bootloader.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried one of the "Previous Linux versions"? Once I couldn't boot after messing around with drivers and X11 and only the 4.2.0-16 kernel version worked for me.

> "I don't have a CD port in my laptop so I can't reboot with physical copy of Ubuntu either."

You don't need a CD, you can just create a Live USB. I recommend **UNetbootin** for doing so.